# what is the name of this vector quadratic trick and howto prove it

Tags: linear-algebra

I encountered using this trick when showing a kernel matrix is positive semi-definite. Please could you show me how to prove it or tell me under what name to find it? Thanks.

$$\sum_i \sum_j z_i x_i x_j z_j = (x^Tz)^2$$

Comment: What are $x_is$ and $z_is$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The LHS is the just the definition of $(x^Tz)^2$ as a matrix product.

$(AB)_{ij} = \sum\limits_k a_{ik}b_{kj}$

Assuming $x = [x_i]$ and $z = [z_i]$ to be column vectors of length $n$:

$x^Tz = \sum\limits_j x_j z_j = x_1 z_1 + x_2 z_2 + \ldots x_n z_n$

Square this as you would any sum of $n$ terms:

$$(x^Tz)^2 = \left(\sum\limits_j x_j z_j\right)^2 = \sum\limits_i \sum\limits_j x_i z_i x_j z_j$$

Comment: thanks. isn't one the sum index in the very last RHS j?

Comment: @ticcky Yes, thanks for catching that!